# How to find previous quarter and display as Q3 0r Q4 etc

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to be able to determine the previous quarter from the current date and display as Q2 or Q3 or Q4 etc.

I have the code to find and display the previous month (see below) but am unable to find a similar one for quarter. Thanks in advance.
`Range("A4") = Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Date), " mmm yy")`

Comment: `qtr = "Q" & CInt(MONTH(DateAdd("m", -3, Date))/3)+1`

Comment: @scottcraner. Thanks Scott, that gives me Q4...what do I need to change to give me the previous quarter ie from todays date I need Q3, cheers.

Comment: `qtr = "Q" & Int(MONTH(DateAdd("m", -3, Date))/3)+1` sorry should be `int` not `cint`

Comment: @scottcraner. Excellent.......thank you.